# Is there an easier way to write this IF statement?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I'm very new to VBA and trying to learn as I go along. I'm 100% sure there is an easier way to condense this code rather than typing `If` statements for each cell and corresponding cell.

Here is the code I'm using:

```vb
Sub Test()
    If Range("B1").Value > 0 Then
        Range("A1").Value = 0
    End If
    
    If Range("B2").Value > 0 Then
        Range("A2").Value = 0
    End If
    
    If Range("B3").Value > 0 Then
        Range("A3").Value = 0
    End If
    
    If Range("B4").Value > 0 Then
        Range("A4").Value = 0
    End If
    
    If Range("B5").Value > 0 Then
        Range("A5").Value = 0
    End If
    
    If Range("B6").Value > 0 Then
        Range("A6").Value = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

[image: Picture]

The range I'm using is A1:A6 then comparing that against values of B1:B6 and saying if B1 > 0 then A1 = 0, then repeat for A2 and B2 and so on.

I know that the solution is probably painfully obvious, but I can't seem to figure out how to do it yet.

Thanks for any help provided!

Comment: `For i = 1 to 6: If Cells(i,2).Value > 0 Then Cells(i,1).Value = 0: Next i`

Comment: Hi Raymond—Thank you so much! This works great and now I'm exploring and learning the cells property. I appreciate this a ton!

Comment: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.cells), always consult the documentation especially if you are not familiar with it. What I will further suggest to the code above is to fully qualify the range reference e.g. `For i = 1 to 6: If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,2).Value > 0 Then ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,1).Value = 0: Next i` to avoid VBA assuming that you are referring to `ActiveSheet` which might not be what you want. @PeterDavid

Comment: Peter, forgive me if this is an absurd question.  You can formulate this in column C without using any vba.  I guess you are performing a VBA study, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You can either

- use a formula [evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.evaluate) in VBA based on a simple Excel formula

```
    =IF(B1:B6,A1:A6,0)
```

to replace the original data in column A or

- write the mentioned formula directly into e.g. `C1` benefitting from the newer dynamic features of version 2019+/MS 365 displaying it as so called spill range *(otherwise you need to enter it as array formula confirming it via **C**trl+**S**hift+**E**nter)*.

**Example call in VBA**

```
Option Explicit                         ' head of code module (force declaration of variables and objects)

Sub Example()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Sheet1                     ' << change to your project's sheet Code(Name)
    Dim data As Variant                 ' provide for a 1-based 2-dim datafield array
    'assign worksheet related evaluation to data
    data = ws.Evaluate("=If(B1:B6,A1:A6,0)")
    'write to target
    ws.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(data), 1).Value = data
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Simplify Multiple `If` Statements

**Microsoft Docs**

- [`Creating Object Variables`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/creating-object-variables)
- [`Const statement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/const-statement)
- [`For Each...Next statement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/for-eachnext-statement)
- [`Range.Resize property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.resize)
- [`Range.EntireRow property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.entirerow)
- [`IsNumeric function`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/isnumeric-function)

**The Code**

- Both procedures do the same. Due to using constants, the first solution can be quickly adapted by modifying values in one place (at the beginning of the code).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ForEachNext()
    
    Const sfCellAddress As String = "B1"
    Const srCount As Long = 6
    
    Const dCol As String = "A"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sValue As Variant
    Dim dCell As Range
    
    For Each sCell In ws.Range(sfCellAddress).Resize(srCount).Cells
        sValue = sCell.Value
        If IsNumeric(sValue) Then ' is a number
            If sValue > 0 Then ' is greater than
                Set dCell = sCell.EntireRow.Columns(dCol)
                dCell.Value = 0
            'Else ' is less than or equal ('sValue <= 0')
            End If
        'Else ' is not a number
        End If
    Next sCell

End Sub

Sub ForEachNextMagicNumbers()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim sCell As Range
    Dim sValue As Variant
    Dim dCell As Range
    
    For Each sCell In ws.Range("B1").Resize(6).Cells
        sValue = sCell.Value
        If IsNumeric(sValue) Then ' is a number
            If sValue > 0 Then ' is greater than
                Set dCell = sCell.EntireRow.Columns("A")
                dCell.Value = 0
            'Else ' is less than or equal ('sValue <= 0')
            End If
        'Else ' is not a number
        End If
    Next sCell

End Sub
```